# Grouping multiple pins to one variable

Tags: pins

I'm new to all of this, but it's there a way to group a cluster of pins to one variable? I don't necessarily want the grouped pounds to be sequential.

Comment: It's called an *array*.

Comment: Does it need to be byte form?

Comment: An array can be made from any data type you like. Google "Arduino Arrays".

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: One example of a application I am considering is a grid of LEDs. I may wait to group some LEDs to look like  constellations. I would like to have variables naming the constellations, that I can't turn on and off like a light switch.

Answer (score 4):

Only if you drop to low-level access, and only if the pins are [on the same port](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation).

```
#define pinset 0x55

 ...

PORTC |= pinset;
delay(1000);
PORTC &= ~pinset;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example of the constellations, consider using an array for each constellation where each element in the array corresponds to an LED output pin. You could simply put a 1 or a 0 in each array element to indicate if you want the corresponding LED output pin on or off. It would be easy then to create a function that you would pass a constellation array and would turn the LED output pins on or off based on the contents of the array.